# ObservableArrayList: How to get type of generic through reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, javafx, observablelist

I have an ObservableList of generic type CHILDITEMS, where `<CHILDITEMS extends PlanItem>`. How would I know what type the ObservableList is during runtime?

```
    /*Get a reference to the child items of the currently viewed item.*/
    ObservableList<CHILDITEMS> childItems = (ObservableList<CHILDITEMS>) viewing.getChildItems();
    /*Set the child items label to the type of the child items.*/
    childItemsLabel.setText("Name of CHILDITEMS class");
```

I can't use getFields because CHILDITEMS isn't really a field. Using getType on the ObservableList.class only returns the generic type "E", rather than what it is at run time.

The CHILDITEM type could be a Goal, Objective, Strategy, or Task. I'd like to know which it is during runtime.

Comment: Generics are a compile-time construct. That is the compiler will use them to check that you haven't accidentally improperly used an Object. At runtime, Your `ObservableList<CHILDITEMS>` becomes an `ObservableList<Object>`. Under the hood, it will make use of casts as in the pre-Generics versions of Java. This means that you can't do what you want without doing lots of `instanceof` tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Romski says in the comments, this information isn't even retained at runtime.

If you know your list is non-empty, and you only put items of the exact type in your list (i.e. your `ObservableList<P>` only contains items of runtime type `P`, not any items that are instances of subclasses of `P`), then you can of course do `list.get(0).getClass()`, but that is an unlikely scenario and not very robust.

You could also consider creating a wrapper for the list, using a type token to retain the type. Something like:

```
public class TypedObservableList<P extends PlanItem> {
    private final Class<P> type ;
    private final ObservableList<P> list ;

    public TypedObservableList(Class<P> type) {
        this.type = type ;
        this.list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public Class<P> getType() {
        return type ;
    }

    public ObservableList<P> getList() {
        return list ;
    }
}
```

Now you end up with lots of code looking like

```
TableView<Goal> goalTable = new TableView<>();
TypedObservableList<Goal> goals = new TypedObservableList<>(Goal.class);
goalTable.setItems(goals.getList());
```

but at least you can now do

```
TypedObservableList<? extends PlanItem> typedList = viewing.getChildItems();
childItemsLabel.setText(typedList.getType().getSimpleName());
```

You haven't said what `viewing` is, but you can perhaps come up with a similar solution in which that class holds the type token, so you'd end up with

```
childItemsLabel.setText(viewing.getChildType().getSimpleName());
```

Comment: It's somewhat of a hacky solution, but with the current limitations in Java, it's the only thing I can do.